# How to get a UTC date string using Microsoft timezone and moment js

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have following timezone data list and i want to convert time of `Samoa Standard Time`  to utc time using moment js.

```
   var timezones = [
                    {
                      "alias":"Dateline Standard Time",
                      "displayName":"(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West"
                    },
                    {
                      "alias":"Samoa Standard Time",
                      "displayName":"(UTC+13:00) Samoa"
                    },
                    {
                       "alias":"UTC-11",
                       "displayName":"(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11"
                    },
                    {
                      "alias":"Aleutian Standard Time",
                      "displayName":"(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands"
                    }   
    ]
```

is this a correct way to get utc time of **2020-02-25T19:30:00 Samoa Standard Time** ?

```
   var m = moment().utcOffset('+13:00');
    m.toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you want

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2

```
var moment = require("moment-timezone");
var input = "05/30/2014 11:21:37 AM";
var format = "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A";
var zone = "Pacific/Samoa";
// construct a moment object
var momentObj = moment.tz(input, format, zone);
// convert it to utc
momentObj.utc();
var finalVal = momentObj.format(format);
console.log(finalVal);
```

Comment: I cannot convert Microsoft time-zones to this "Pacific/Samoa" format

Comment: @ sv12  {
                      "alias":"Samoa Standard Time",
                      "displayName":"(UTC+13:00) Samoa"
                    }   as shown in question